# How to change side and direction arrow in dropdown-submenu?

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-modal

I create menu with dropdown-submenu.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    float:left;
}

.left-submenu {
    float: none;
}

.left-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    border-radius: 6px 0px 6px 6px;
    left: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    right: 98%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something that is a really really really long string here</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu left-submenu"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Try left</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">shorter things</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">shorter things</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">shorter things</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu left-submenu"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More else</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to change side and direction arrow in dropdown-submenu "Try left"?

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/5BUXu/20/

p.s. Want to get same result on picture

[image: p.s. want to get same result on picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to 'flip the script'. The arrow is in an `:after` in the bootstrap CSS, you need to rewrite that, flip all that makes it appear right, like this:

```
.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    border-right-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5BUXu/21/)

So the `float` is now left instead of right, the `border-right-width` is now 5px instead of the `border-left-width`, and the `margin-right` is now `margin-left`.

For one item to have a left-arrow and one item to have a right arrow you either need to add a class or when you know the amount of items is fixed, you can work with nth-child selector. Like this:

[With class added](https://jsfiddle.net/5BUXu/22/)

`<li class="dropdown-submenu right-submenu"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">`

```
.dropdown-submenu.right-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    border-right-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

[With nth-child selector](https://jsfiddle.net/5BUXu/23/)

```
.dropdown-submenu:nth-child(4)>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    border-right-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But this solution change arrow in all of sub-menu on left. How to make the price was only in dropdown-submenu "Try left" to left, Dropdown-submenu "More else" must stay right?

Comment: Then there should be a class 'right-submenu' on <li>'s that need the arrow the other way. Or if the amount of items in the list is fixed, you can work with child-selectors.

Comment: So either this: https://jsfiddle.net/5BUXu/22/ or this https://jsfiddle.net/5BUXu/23/